# Can't dismiss Admob Interstitial Ads by pressing Back key button of Android device

Tags: android, admob

I am using latest Ads library `('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0')`

Recently, It is unable to close an Interstitial ads by pressing Back key button. I have to tap on "Close" button from Ads UI to dismiss the Ads.

Any body had same problem?
Is it a new feature of Admob?

```
  MobileAds.initialize(this);
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
tvTitle.setOnClickListener(v -> {
if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
interstitialAd.show();
}
});
```

Comment: Same here, 'Back' button stopped closing ads.

Comment: I have also noticed the change on Android recently. I actually agree with this change. It now matches how iOS works. For me Android full screen add revenue has always been extremely low due to the user pressing the back button and not clicking the close on the activity.

Answer (score 3):

I've this too. I've talked with people at AdMob and asked if they changed the behavior of their ads and they confirmed that they did. It's no longer possible to use the "Back" button to dismiss the interstitial ad and they told me that no changes are required on my side. I guess users must use the "Close" or "X" button within the ad itself to close it.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is sometimes the CLOSE AD "X" is not visibile and users must force close the app

Comment: If that is the case they are making developer's app not user friendly and users may uninstall the app due to frustrations. Also like Zbarcea Christian said when users cannot find X button immediately they will force close the app and uninstall it.

Comment: It seems like the back button is working again on Admob ads. Did you notice the same in the latest versions?