# Admob Interstitial ad is not closing when user presses back button on android 7,8,9 but works fine on android 10 and 6

Tags: android, admob

when an Admob interstitial ad is shown to the user, pressing back button does not close the ad on android 7-9 whereas doing same on android 6 and android 10 closes the interstitial ad.
i am using dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
```

is it an issue in admob sdk or it can be related to my interstitial ad implementation?
p.s. i have implemented the code like this:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial
and it used to work fine a few days back.

Comment: Same here, i posted on admob sdk group regarding this issue:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/t8Ln93xvi3g

In the last days i see more and more reports regarding this issue.

Comment: Addtionally, i have an observation: this issue somehow relates to google play services or maybe Ad id of the device. because when i clear data & cache for play services from the device with issue...it gets fixed for that device.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue with Android 10 in Android Studio Emulator (Pixel 2 API 29). Press Back Button when showing Interstitial Ads: Nothing happens.  Also, I noted that "onBackPressed()" in my activity is not called. I assume that the InterstitialAd activity (Google?) takes control here.

Comment: I have also noticed the change on Android recently. I actually agree with this change. It now matches how iOS works. For me Android full screen add revenue has always been extremely low due to the user pressing the back button and not clicking the close on the activity.